# Como posicionar divs no estilo do Tumblr

Tags: html, css

Como eu posso posicionar as divs desta maneira? Lembrando que ele não posiciona em linha vertical, sempre em horizontal ele vai tipo encaixando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar a propriedade CSS flex-wrap: wrap; ? Não tenho certeza se ela dá o mesmo efeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executa o código e veja na pagina inteira:

```css
*{ 
 margin: 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#columns {
 column-width: 320px;
  -moz-column-width: 320px;
  -webkit-column-width: 320px;
 column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  width: 90%;
 max-width: 1100px;
 margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#columns .card {
  width: 355px;
 background: #fefefe;
 border: 2px solid #fcfcfc;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(34, 25, 25, 0.4);
 margin: 0 2px 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 transition: opacity .4s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
   column-break-inside:avoid;
}

img{
  max-width:100%;
}

figcaption{
  font-family: "arial", sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="columns">
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras risus elit, accumsan sit amet commodo rhoncus, dictum a diam. Aliquam laoreet sit amet lacus vel placerat. </figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras risus elit, accumsan sit amet commodo rhoncus, dictum a diam. Aliquam laoreet sit amet lacus vel placerat. </figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/28/19/40/photography-1166895_960_720.jpg">
    <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
 </div>
```